# May I use variables and concatenate in Puppet resource names?

Tags: ruby, puppet, variable-names

I'm wondering if one can put variables in resource names, for example:

```
$c6release = $::operatingsystemmajrelease
  ##  [EPEL(5, 6, or 7)-x86_64]
yumrepo { 'EPEL' + $c6release + '-x86_64':  ##  This is the part I'm asking about.
    baseurl  => "http://repo.centos.com/cobbler/repo_mirror/EPEL" + $c6release + "-x86_64/",
    gpgcheck => false,
    enabled  => true,
    priority => '2';
}
```

I've been able to use arrays to make multiple file resources before, but I can't seem to use it in the way described above.

I've found the following in my research:

http://www.nico.schottelius.org/blog/puppet-name-is-not-as-expected-but-classname/ (This is for Puppet 2.7, though)

https://ask.puppet.com/question/13266/trying-to-use-namevar-list-with-name-or-title-variable/

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_resources.html

Could one use a defined resource type to take care of this?

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defined_types.html

Anyway, the above seem to indicate that I can use variables for Puppet resource names, but I can't seem to get them to work.

May one use variables in resource names?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the Puppet Language supports interpolation inside resource names. See the documentation [here](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/3/reference/lang_variables.html#interpolation).

What you need:

```
  $c6release = $::operatingsystemmajrelease
  yumrepo { "EPEL${c6release}-x86_64":
    baseurl  => "http://repo.centos.com/cobbler/repo_mirror/EPEL${c6release}-x86_64/",
    gpgcheck => false,
    enabled  => true,
    priority => '2',
  }
```

Comment: Also he should really just use `$::operatingsystemmajrelease` in the interpolation.

Comment: // , Yes, I likely shall. This is just an example, though. Also, I have begun to pay a little more attention to that 80 col puppet-lint limit.

Comment: // , Speaking of puppet-lint, I guess I'd ask another question. Does using this sort of interpolation make for good Puppet style?

Comment: @Nathan Basanese, I think you need to review etiquette for editing another user's answers.  Bash has complex rules for variable interpolation that do not apply in Puppet.  If you have a comment on my answer, please make a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I said in my edit summary that you also added a syntax error.  Actually, I see I copied the semi-colon from your question.  The semi-colon after priority is allowed by Puppet, but it is not recommended and violates the Style Guide.  I've updated my answer to show preferred syntax.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I'm not so sure that defining a short alias for a long ugly string like $::operatingsystemmajrelease is always necessarily bad style.

Comment: @NathanBasanese It's sometimes impossible to avoid the 80 column limit that Puppet-lint complains about, so a lot of people simply disable that check.

Comment: @NathanBasanese  By the way, Puppet's syntax was historically modelled on Nagios by Puppet's author.

Comment: @AlexHarvey The style is the same between the two, but one is obviously slightly more computationally efficient. Also, the Puppet style guidelines have been 140 chars/line for over a year and not 80, so that guideline is rather reasonable now.

Comment: Ta, didn't know that. I'm not sure I'd enable 140 characters either.  Keeping the lines short is a good habit for readability, but if it's not possible, it's not possible.

Comment: @AlexHarvey Honestly, people have been widely disabling the 140 char check too. I am pretty sure I ignore it most of the time. People not reading the release notes for puppet-lint or linter-puppet-lint (which I maintain) gave me a headache because of the invalid arg (80-->140) and how puppet-lint outputs errors to stdout.